# Is there a way to tell gradle which profiles should be used for the tests?

Tags: spring, gradle, docker, spring-boot, build

I use the yml configuration files pattern `application-{default,dev,production}.yml`.

To define which configuration application will use, I fix the environment `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev` so when the spring app run, it choose the correct configuration.

I have now theses two issues:

1. The `./gradlew build` command also run the test command, test need to have the correct configuration as the application does when it start.
2. My jenkins does not have access to the database and the units tests keep failing.

Which make make ask:

1. Does the build command tries all the datasource in order ? Is there a way to specify the spring boot active profile ?
2. Is there another different approach for deploying spring-boots app in production from jenkins ?
3. Does anyone has a workaround except

   ```
   ./gradlew -x test build
   ```

   *This is not what I want.*

   Neither adding `@ActiveProfile("dev")` to my tests because this require source code modification.

Answer (score 0):

Simply Create multiple property files.For Example:
    application.properties
    application-test.properties
    application-production.properties
    
    Provide different properties based on profile and
    Below you can specify
    which profile to load in you gradle.build file

```
def profile = "test"
bootRun {
 args = ["--spring.profiles.active="+profile]
}
```

Put below code in the end of gradle file